# Why i can't insert double to SQLite table

Tags: java, android

I tried a lot of way to insert double number to SQLite table but it keep return false but I don't know why.
I want the acconut remember the money

I designer a mobile bank on android studio

this is the activety to sign up

```
    package com.example.bcbanks;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText username;
private EditText password;
private EditText money;
private EditText cpassword;
private Button signup;
private ImageButton goback;
DBHelper DB;

@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username2);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    money = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
    cpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password3);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerbt);
    goback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.goback);
    DB = new DBHelper(this);


    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String repass = cpassword.getText().toString();
            String bill = (money.getText().toString());

            if(user.equals("")||pass.equals("")||repass.equals("")||bill.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Please enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{if(pass.equals(repass)){
                Boolean checkuser = DB.checkusername(user);
                if(checkuser==false){

                    Boolean insert = DB.insertData(user, pass, Double.valueOf(bill));
                    if(insert==true){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "User already exists! please sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "Passwords not matching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            } }
    });
    goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}
```

}

it is the DBHelper

```
    package com.example.bcbanks;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DBNAME = "Login.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase MyDB) {
    MyDB.execSQL("create Table users(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT, money REAL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase MyDB, int i, int i1) {
    MyDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
}

public Boolean insertData(String username, String password, Double money){
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("username", username);
    contentValues.put("password", password);
    contentValues.put("money", money);
    long result = MyDB.insert("users", null, contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public Boolean updatepassword(String username, String password)
{
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("password", password);
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        long result = DB.update("users", contentValues, "username=?", new String[]{username});
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Boolean updatemoney(String username, double money)
{
    SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("money", money);
    Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        long result = DB.update("users", contentValues, "username=?", new String[]{username});
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Boolean checkusername(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{username});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public Boolean checkpass(String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{password});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public Boolean checkusernamepassword(String username, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ? and password = ?", new String[] {username,password});
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

here is the code i think it got prooblem

```
    public Boolean insertData(String username, String password, Double money){
SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("username", username);
contentValues.put("password", password);
contentValues.put("money", money);
long result = MyDB.insert("users", null, contentValues);
if(result==-1)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

in method insertdata it alaway return false

Comment: Take a look at this first - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Use [SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) and capture what exception error you are getting.